# Message signing/encryption with Thunderbird and Kleopatra

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, encryption, kde

How do I make Thunderbird use my certificates stored in Kleopatra (KDE)? When I try to import certificates it says it's looking for PKCS12 files, but I can't find any. I'm not sure where Kleopatra stores keys, but I assume it takes them from gnupg's directory (`~/.gnupg`). So how do I make the two play together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your certificate and private key from Kleopatra (only PEM format supported). Convert the file to PKCS#12 format with the `openssl pkcs12` command (find tutorials on Google). Import the result into Thunderbird's certificate manager.

Answer (score 1):

While you asked about Kleopatra specifically, since you mentioned GPG you might be interested in the [Engimail](http://enigmail.net) addon for Thunderbird, which simplifies combining Thunderbird and GnuPG a lot.